# What is the proper way to calculate latency in omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have written a simulation module. For measuring latency, I am using this:

```
simTime().dbl() - tempLinkLayerFrame->getCreationTime().dbl();
```

Is this the proper way ? If not then please suggest me or a sample code would be very helpful.

Also, is the `simTime()` latency is the actual latency in terms of micro
seconds which I can write in my research paper? or do I need to
scale it up?

Also, I found that the channel data rate and channel delay has no impact on the link latency instead if I vary the trigger duration the latency varies. For example

```
timer = new cMessage("SelfTimer");
scheduleAt(simTime() + 0.000000000249, timer);
```

If this is not the proper way to trigger simple module recursively then please suggest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both `simTime` and `getCreationTime` use the OMNeT++ class for representing time, you can operate on them directly, because that class overloads the relevant operators. Going with what the manual says, I'd recommend using a signal for the measurements (e.g., `emit(latencySignal, simTime() - tempLinkLayerFrame->getCreationTime());`).

`simTime()` is in seconds, not microseconds.

Regarding your last question, this code will have problems if you use it for all nodes, and you start all those nodes at the same time in the simulation. In that case you'll have perfect synchronization of all nodes, meaning you'll only see collisions in the first transmission. Therefore, it's probably a good idea to add a random jitter to every newly scheduled message at the start of your simulation.

Comment: Thanks Rens for your reply. Please suggest how much jitter to introdue in my application module.

Comment: @user3243499 I'm not sure I can give you an authoritative answer, but if you look at [this section of the OMNeT++ manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec126), an example jitter of `normal(0s, 0.001s)` is used. You could do some quick simulations to see if that's reasonable. I'd suggest having a `par('sendJitter')` in the C++ code, and a `volatile double sendJitter = normal(0s, 0.001s)` in the NED file.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, now I understood why introducing jitter makes sense. One more help please. I have introduced channel datarate and delay using gate1<-->{datarate=100Mbps;delay=5us;}<-->gate2. But while simulating I found that this datarate and delay does not have any impact on my latency. Also the packets get delivered even if I change the datarate to 0 Mbps. Please explain this and how to actually use this channel. [I have checked all over the web, but unfortunately did not found any helpful links on it]

Comment: I'm not really sure how those connections work. All of the work I use OMNeT++ is related to wireless networks, and there we don't use the cChannel that comes with OMNeT++, so I'd suggest asking another question about that. What you could try is using a debugger to inspect what happens when you set the data rate to 0.

Comment: ok, but wireless networks also has data rates. So how would you simulate those data rates in OMNet++ in your case ?

Comment: They're normally dynamic (dependent on distance, objects between receivers, etc). Simulation packages for wireless networks include code that computes the properties of the channel at a particular range and point in time. This process basically simulates the real world directly, instead of having a fixed data rate -- the data rate is only used to specify which frequencies are used.